# how to convert excel Custom column values into string type in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

Excel table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Mar-21 |
| Cell 3 | Apr-21 |
| Cell 3 | Dec-21 |

Expected CSV table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Mar-21 |
| Cell 3 | Apr-21 |
| Cell 3 | Dec-21 |

however, due to excel data format issue, the Column B is automatically accepting the column values as date (e.g. 01/03/2021, 01/04/2021 and 01/12/2021).

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(excel_dir).rglob('*.xlsx'):
    print(path.name)
    df= pd.read_excel(path)
    if 'Wave' in  df.columns:
      df = pd.read_excel((path), dtype = {'Wave': str})
    else:
      df = pd.read_excel(path)

    file_name = os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0]

    csv_file_name = f'{file_name}.csv'

    df.to_csv(os.path.join(csv_dir,csv_file_name), index = False)
```

Using `dtype` as `str` I am not able to convert Column B as expected column values. Rather it is giving me result like `01/11/2021  12:00:00 am`.

*How can I convert excel into csv without changing Column B values?*

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column to a string in the format you want using the `.dt` accessor.  Note that the `test.xlsx` file looks like:

[image: cell names in A and dates in B with headers]

Column B has dates and is formatted as `mmm-yy`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df)
print()
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].dt.strftime('%b-%y')
print(df)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index = False)
```

Output (terminal):

```
  Column A   Column B
0   Cell 1 2021-03-01
1   Cell 2 2021-04-01
2   Cell 3 2021-12-01

  Column A Column B
0   Cell 1   Mar-21
1   Cell 2   Apr-21
2   Cell 3   Dec-21
```

Output (test.csv):

```
Column A,Column B
Cell 1,Mar-21
Cell 2,Apr-21
Cell 3,Dec-21
```